# How to apply jquery code to different targets without rewriting existing code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to execute existing jquery code but apply it to alternate targets?

**EXAMPLE**

```
$('#btn1').click(function() {
    $('#div1').fadeOut()
});
```

Can this code be reused to execute from #btn2 and target #div2 without rewriting the code.

**SOLUTION**

```
<a href="#"class="btn" data-id="35">Click</a>

$('.btn').click(function() {
    $('#div'+$(this).data('id')).fadeOut()
});
```

Comment: No, obviously you need to rewrite it to make different things happen?

Comment: Can this method be used to alter functions e.g instead of fadeOut Can I replace the left part of marginLeft if my data-id="Right"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution :

```
$('#btn1,#btn2').click(function() {
    $('#div'+this.id.slice(-1)).fadeOut()
});
```

If you want something more general, working for any "btnxxx", then you can do this :

```
$('[id^=btn]').click(function() {
    $('#div'+this.id.slice(3)).fadeOut()
});
```

But then a class and a data-attribute would be better :

```
<span class=btn data-btnid=35>AAA</span>

$('.btn').click(function() {
    $('#div'+$(this).data('btnid')).fadeOut()
});
```

---

EDIT following the (not so related) comment :

Here's another example :

```
<span class=btn data-btnid=35 data-dir="Left">AAA</span>

$('.btn').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $target = $('#div'+$(this).data('btnid'));
    var animation = {};
    animation['margin'+$this.data('dir')] = '0';
    $target.animate(animation);
});
```

Comment: `this.id.replace("btn", "div")` might be working better with higher numbers

Comment: @Bergi I don't see why it would work better than `this.id.slice(3)`. Did you comment before you saw the second part ?

Comment: Yes, I did. It's basically equivalent :-)

Comment: can this be done with classes instead of id so i name several buttons "btn1".

Comment: @DreamTeK You could add a class and a data attribute. See edit.

Comment: Can this method be used to alter functions e.g instead of fadeOut Can I replace the left part of marginLeft if my data-id="Right"

Comment: Well, yes. You can test the value of `$(this).data('orientation')` or whatever in your function.

Comment: Please could you pass an example: I am struggling
.animate({'margin'+$(this).data('Col')+':' 0})

Comment: I edited to show how you can use such a data value to fill a js object. If you still have questions, consider making them independent questions, please.